# MongoDB Update Array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, push, insert-update

I have a document structure like

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52263922f5ebf05115bf550e"),
    "Fields" : [
        {
            "Field" : "Lot No",
            "Rules" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "Field" : "RMA No",
            "Rules" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to update by using the following code to push into the Rules Array which will hold objects.

```javascript
db.test.update({
    "Fields.Field":{$in:["Lot No"]}
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        "Fields.Field.$.Rules": {
            "item_name": "my_item_two",
            "price": 1
        }
    }
}, false, true);
```

But I get the following error:

> can't append to array using string field name [Field]

How do I do the update?

Comment: I think you have a superfluous `Field` in your $addToSet-Operator. Try `$addToSet: { "Fields.$.Rules": ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gone too deep with that wildcard `$`. You match for an item in the `Fields` array, so you get a access on that, with: `Fields.$`. This expression returns the first match in your `Fields` array, so you reach its fields by `Fields.$.Field` or `Fields.$.Result`.

Now, lets update the `update`:

```
db.test.update({
    "Fields.Field": "Lot No"
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        "Fields.$.Rules": {
            'item_name': "my_item_two",
            'price':1
        }
    }
}, false, true);
```

Please note that I've shortened the `query` as it is equal to your expression.