# mongodb: update array item inside of a post inside of a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to update an item inside an array which is a part of a post. 
I did find this which looks closest to what I'm looking for: [MongoDB Update Array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600791/mongodb-update-array-element)

But I dont have the specific post lined up first like this example seems to show. But I need to find the specific post using _id first, then update an item in the array from the resulted post.

Can I do this with one query or do I need to find the item first to then update it like the example shows in the other answer?

In the below json how could I update the first posts comments: first comment?

EDIT:

```
[{
    "_id": "52c06c86b78a091f26000001",
    "comments": [
        {
            "user_id": "52ad97bab142627664000001 ",
            "username": "phacer",
            "comment": "nice dress!!!",
            "created": 1390668491909,
            "_id": "_SvF-Ag4d6wFf9QR1KdAdFIpcCyI3cqm2F4rl3w7rdk="
        },
        {
            "user_id": "52ad97bab142627664000001 ",
            "username": "phacer",
            "comment": "nice dress!!!",
            "created": 1390668491909,
            "_id": "_SvF-Ag4d6wFf9QR1KdAdFIpcCyI3cqm2F4rl3w7rdk="
        }
    ],
    "desc": "Something somethingson",
    "hate": [],
    "imageurl": "some url",
    "love": [
        {
            "user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001",
            "username": "asd",
            "created": 1390652212592
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "y": 29.3,
            "brand": "Zara",
            "type": "Bow Tie",
            "x": 20,
            "color": "Black"
        }
    ],
    "user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001"
},
{
    "_id": "52c06c86b78a091f26000001",
    "comments": [
        {
            "user_id": "52ad97bab142627664000001 ",
            "username": "phacer",
            "comment": "nice dress!!!",
            "created": 1390668491909,
            "_id": "_SvF-Ag4d6wFf9QR1KdAdFIpcCyI3cqm2F4rl3w7rdk="
        }
    ],
    "desc": "Something somethingson",
    "hate": [],
    "imageurl": "some url",
    "love": [
        {
            "user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001",
            "username": "asd",
            "created": 1390652212592
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "y": 29.3,
            "brand": "Zara",
            "type": "Bow Tie",
            "x": 20,
            "color": "Black"
        }
    ],
    "user_id": "52add4f4344e8ca867000001"
}]
```

Comment: You should be able to update the array based on a query in one operation. Why don't you post some sample json and explain what you want the update to do and we might be able to post an example for you.

Comment: @cirrus I've added some json, thanks.

Comment: +1 for $elemMatch - but I'd be tempted simply to put the comments into a collection of their own if I had a choice. That way I could use an index on user_id, _id and post_id. Easy and fast to add and update. Deleting a post and all the comments would be more involved, but that's a less common operation I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `$elemMatch` ([Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)) like this:

```
.update({'_id': '52c06c86b78a091f26000001', 'comments' : {$elemMatch: {'_id': '_SvF-Ag4d6wFf9QR1KdAdFIpcCyI3cqm2F4rl3w7rdk='}}}, {$set : {'comments.$.comment': 'Lame dress!'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use positional operators in Mongo to access the particular array element like below

```
db.collection.update( { _id: 52c06c86b78a091f26000001 }, { $set: { "comments.$1.comment" : "dress" } } )
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great. What if I dont know which of the comments I'm updating. If I would find it by the _id for instance?