# Setting value of a specific child element mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following database:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4c13d7db9acd913ce6e08"),
    "state" : "helloworld",
    "items" : [
        {
            "guid" : 123,
            "uniqueId" : 0
        },
        {
            "guid" : 124,
            "uniqueId" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to set the `guid` of the `items.uniqueId = 1` field to 125, so that the result will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4c13d7db9acd913ce6e08"),
    "state" : "helloworld",
    "items" : [
        {
            "guid" : 123,
            "uniqueId" : 0
        },
        {
            "guid" : 125,
            "uniqueId" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```
> db.test.update( {'items.uniqueId' : 1} , { $set : { 'items.guid' : 125 }} )
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (items of items.guid) to traverse the element ({items: [ { guid: 123.0, uniqueId: 0.0 }, { guid: 124.0, uniqueId: 1.0 } ]})"
    }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Update Array element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600791/mongodb-update-array-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator together with the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update to change the `guid` field. The **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** will identify the correct element in the array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
db.collection.update({ "items.uniqueId": 1 }, 
    {
        "$set": {
            "items.$.guid": 125
        }
    }
)
```

If you want to increment the value by 1, use the **[`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)** update operator

```
db.collection.update({ "items.uniqueId": 1 }, 
    {
        "$inc": {
            "items.$.guid": 1
        }
    }
)
```